# How to add wordpress pagination

Tags: pagination, wpdb

i must use pagination. Where can i found good tutorial?

`$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ogloszenia_kupione WHERE klient_id = $current_user->ID");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague but if it's documentation you are looking for then a good place to start would be:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: but this is example of post paggination i wont paggination $wpdb.

Comment: Sorry, I just cannot understand what do you exactly need?

Comment: ok thx, i found http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2010/11/25/pagination-using-paginate_links/ is good working example.